# INSERTING data from Excel VBA macros to a SQL SVR 2008 DB

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, excel, vba

I am using a VBA macro in Excel to INSERT data from cells into a SQL Server 2008 database.

I have placed data in the cells in an order e.g. 1,2,3,4,5...etc.

When the VBA code INSERTS the above numbers into a column in a database..the numbers are not ordered, they appear like this 2,3,1,4,5..

Is there any reason why the data is being arranged like this? It happens with text aswell as numbers.

Here is some of my code;

---

```
Dim val1 As String, val2 As String, val3 As String, val4 As String

val1 = Range("B142").Value
val2 = Range("C142").Value
val3 = Range("D142").Value
val4 = Range("E142").Value

conn.Open sConnString

Dim item4 As String
item4 = "INSERT INTO [IndustrialComp].[dbo].[Network]("
item4 = item4 & "  [server_name],[network_name],[license],[version]"

item4 = item4 & "  )Values("
item4 = item4 & "  '" & val1 & "', '" & val2 & "', '" & val3 & "','" & val4 & "')"

'row 2

Dim val5 As String, val6 As String, val7 As String, val8 As String

val5 = Range("B143").Value
val6 = Range("C143").Value
val7 = Range("D143").Value
val8 = Range("E143").Value

Dim item5 As String
item5 = "INSERT INTO [IndustrialComp].[dbo].[Network]("
item5 = item5 & "  [server_name],[network_name],[license],[version]"

item5 = item5 & "  )Values("
item5 = item5 & "  '" & val5 & "', '" & val6 & "', '" & val7 & "','" & val8 & "')"
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Databases are not inherently ordered in the order things are added. Rather, they have keys which can be used to define different orders.

If you want them to appear in a certain order, e.g. the order they were added, you will have to add a column to hold the row number, or whatever it is you want to sort by.

If you want the sort-order column to be added automatically you can use an `IDENTITY` column:

```
CREATE TABLE Network(
-- This column will be filled in automatically starting with 1
    ix int identity primary key, 
    -- These are your other columns.
    [server_name] nvarchar(50),
    [network_name] nvarchar(50),
    [license] nvarchar(50),
    [version] nvarchar(50)
)
```

(`ix` is short for index and is commonly used for identity columns. You could use `id` if it makes more sense.)
Then, when reading data, remember to use `ORDER BY ix`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. The table has already been created in SQL server. Do I therefore need to refer myself back to initial creation/values on the Database?

Comment: @user3013325 The table can only order by things which are in the table. If you want to order by the order you add the rows you must put the order you add the rows as a column. How you do that is up to you.